# LoadLibrary fails when called from .pyd file, succeeds when called from python

Tags: python, c++, dll

I have a python module `my_module` written in C++ using `boost-python`. This module exports function `load_my_class`:

```cpp
MyClass * load_my_class()
{
    auto lib = LoadLibraryW(L"C:/full/path/to/library/MyClass.dll");
    if (!lib)
    {
        printf("LoadLibraryW failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto myInitialize = reinterpret_cast<myInitializeFn>(GetProcAddress(lib, "myInitialize"));
    if (!myInitialize)
        return nullptr;
    return myInitialize();
}
```

This function is then called from python:

```py
from my_module import load_my_class
my_class = load_my_class()
```

This code prints `LoadLibraryW failed: 126`. However, if I load the library from python prior to calling `load_my_class()`:

```py
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:/full/path/to/library/MyClass.dll")
my_class = load_my_class()
```

subsequent `LoadLibrary` call will succeed. `MyClass.dll` depends only on CRT and libraries located in the same folder.

Why python can successfully load the library, but module one can not?

Comment: Maybe there are additional DLL's that this DLL relies on to load correctly, and your C++ code doesn't have access to them, or some other issue.  A failed `LoadLibrary` doesn't just mean that the specific DLL couldn't be found -- it may still be found, but the DllMain() of the loaded DLL returns an error.

Comment: Also, you could debug that DLL and if you haven't done so, add a `DllMain()` function to see if the DLL is being loaded from C++.  If you place a breakpoint in `DllMain()` and it is hit, but you still get the error that the DLL couldn't be loaded, then that is an indication of what I mentioned in the first comment that is causing the issue.  More information on [DllMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no, `DllMain` is not called. I've double checked dependencies - they are located in the same folder. Right now I'm wrapping `LoadLibrary` call in `SetDllDirectoryW(full_path_to_libdir)/SetDllDirectoryW(nullptr)`, but I don't feel safe doing that.